# Spring Batch pausing and restarting a job

Tags: java, spring-batch, job-scheduling

Is there any way to make a job stop and resume from the same point in Spring Batch? (Dynamically not statically)

Maybe launching a new job that would stop the current one? Has anybody ever done something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be a matter of calling `JobExecution::stop()` and then re-run it with the same set of parameters. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/d4575729e7f57e226f02).

Comment: Is the only way to call JobExecution::stop() to launch another job?

Comment: @Rollerball No, as you can see in the example.